# How to get ajax response using custom attribute in php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working with ajax with php,I have following buttons in loop,I just want to
show/fetch data(number) on correct place/div using "attr" in jquery but not working in my side

Here is my button in loop

```
<?php
foreach //

 <button class="btn likebutn_r" data-datac="1" data-datacw="<?php echo $WalletAddress; ?>" data-datacr="<?php echo $rev->id; ?>" data-datacoin="<?php echo $rev->coin_id; ?>" data-datasymbol="<?php echo $rev->symbol; ?>" id="show<?php echo "1";?>"  value="1" type="submit"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/img/thumb.png" height="24" width="24"></button>
 
 <div id="<?php echo $rev->id; ?>">12(dynamic)</div>
endforeach//
```

Here is my ajax code,How can i get data using custom attribute (via pass ReviewId)? Thanks in advance

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn').click(function (e) {
            var vote = $(this).data('datac');
            var review = $(this).data('datacr');
            var CoinId = $(this).data('datacoin');
            var symbol = $(this).data('datasymbol');
            var WalletAddress = $(this).data('datacw');

            var datacrp = $(this).data('datacrp');
            $('#' + review).hide();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>main/AddVote',
                data: {
                    vote: vote,
                    review: review,
                    CoinId: CoinId,
                    symbol: symbol,
                    WalletAddress: WalletAddress
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#' + review).html(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "not working" means what _exactly_? Give us a clue. What debugging have you done? We can't easily run this code because it relies on server-side PHP, and on data we don't have access to and you haven't provided. e.g. to start with, when you run `var review = $(this).data('datacr');` what is the value of `review` afterwards? You can log it to the console to find out, or use the JS debugger. The code _looks_ like it should work based on what you've said but perhaps there is something in the context which isn't obvious here.

Comment: Unless the actual PHP code is relevant, please post the final HTML instead. You can view it by pressing Ctrl+U in your browser. Next, please state *exactly* how and where your code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help you.
*Reminder the js code below have to implement inside the php file so the Post url ajax will get the value.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e){ 
  var allData = {
    "vote": $(this).data('datac'),
    "review": $(this).data('datacr'),
    "CoinId": $(this).data('datacoin'),
    "symbol": $(this).data('datasymbol'),
    "WalletAddress": $(this).data('walletaddress'),
  }
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:'test.com',
      data: allData,
      success: function(data) {
            $(this).attr('data-datac', data['vote']);
            $(this).attr('data-datacr', data['review']);
            $(this).attr('datacoin', data['CoinId']);
            $(this).attr('data-datasymbol', data['review']);
            $(this).attr('data-datacoin', data['review']);
            $(this).attr('data-datasymbol', data['symbol']);
            $(this).attr('data-walletaddress', data['WalletAddress']);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<button 
class="btn likebutn_r" 
data-datac="1" 
data-datacw="teste"
data-datacr="asdfasf" 
data-datacoin="asdfasdf"
data-datasymbol="asdfasdf"
data-datacrp="asfsa"
id="31"
data-walletaddress="dsaf"
value="1" 
type="submit">Hello</button>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: not working , not hide existing

Comment: Just to be clear you want to modify the data after ajax response ?

Comment: just want to hide old/existing data

Comment: i want when i click then "current" data should hide and "new" data(coming from db via ajax) should display, Thats it

Comment: Tip for answering: If you're going to post a runnable code snippet, it should actually _run_, not fail immediately when you try to use it

Comment: So you have the data from the php which you displeyed on the button, you have to change the data and then post the new data, after you post the change data you have to update the data on db after that the new data will display after realoding the page

Comment: @AdrianBiba: Yes everything is done, queries are working properly just need to hide existing data, new data also fetching but need to remove "current" data,Please help

Comment: @amitfiles you are not very clear what you what, but let me understand you want to remove data from the button on the post success ?

Comment: @AdrianBiba: Let me explain: I have button and below that button "counter"(number) showing so i want whenever i click on that button then "existing/old number" should hide and "new numbers" (via ajax coming) should display , how can i do this ?

Comment: @AdrianBiba: like "replacewith" ajax

Comment: @amitfiles I updated the code check it please

Comment: @AdrianBiba: not working

Comment: @amitfiles check the network if post is status 200 because it's not gonna change the data if the post isn't post status 200

Comment: @amitfiles I also update the code this should work fine if post status is 200

Comment: @AdrianBiba: will not work because i have dislike button also in loop

Comment: so the click event its not working?